# What language do I write automation scripts in

Tags: automation, continuous-integration

I recently read both Continuous Delivery and the Continuous Integration books. They were both very insistent that I automate tasks like provisioning environments and such. My question is what do I write my 'automation scripts' for lets say provisioning a linux instance with postgres and git.

I've seen some stuff suggesting bash, but for this particular usecase I was interested in StackOverflow's opinions :)

I also saw something about perl and python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can write them in any language you want, as long as it can be run from a command line environment (which is just about any).

That said, some are better choices than others, depending on your environment and what you're familiar with.

The most basic is Bash for a Unix environment, because Bash is generally available in any *nix environment, which makes it easily portable. It's also what you use directly in the command line, so it's generally pretty easy to test.

Beyond that, it becomes a matter of choice. For example, my server has Ruby scripts for getting up Git repositories (written by my predecessor), PHP scripts for automating tasks for one of my (PHP/CodeIgniter) websites, and Perl scripts for my server monitoring software (written by the software provider).

Answer (score 1):

I would write them in some language that I know best, and maybe have some reusable code in. For example, I've been developing in PHP for quite some time, and even if it is considered a web-language, it's quite powerful in CLI as well.

My vote would be any of these:

- Python
- Bash
- Perl
- PHP
- Ruby

Comment: Yeah, actually this list is in the exact prioritized order that I'd put them myself, for system scripting tasks (after trying, and still using) most of these (not Ruby yet).

Answer (score 0):

How about Groovy, Jython? I found a lot scripts written in that.

Answer (score 0):

Language selection for writing automation tools is matter of choice.But still it is recommended to analyse what suits well for our requirement. For example any work related to MS excel and data extraction related ,usually we prefer **VB script**.

Likewise for most of thing **Python** suits well.it is solid language, available in cross platform.Fairy large selection of libraries and its dynamic nature makes attractive to automate most of lengthy things.

**Java** is also good choice in many situations if we  handle things like heap space and exceptions well.

Other than these, can go for **Perl,Bash,Ruby** and many likewise.